# Hash & Birthday Paradox with a different perspective

Tags: algorithm, hash, random, probability-theory

Background: Many people are familiar with the so-called Birthday "Paradox" that, in a room of 23 people, there is a better than 50/50 chance that two of them will share the same birthday. In its more general form for n people, the probability of no two people sharing the same birthday is p(n) = 365! / (365^n *(365-n)!). Similar calculations are used for understanding hash-space sizes, cryptographic attacks, etc.

Motivation: The reason for asking the following question is actually related to understanding a specific financial market behavior. However a variant on the "Birthday Paradox" problem fits exactly as an analogy and is likely to be of wider interest to people with different backgrounds. My question is therefore framed in these more familiar terms, as follows.

Question: There are a total of 60 people in a room. Of these, it turns out that there are 11 (eleven) PAIRS of people who share the same birthday, and one TRIPLE (i.e. group of 3 people) who have the same birthday. The remaining 60 - 2*11 - 3 = 35 people have different birthdays. Assuming a population in which any day is equally likely for a birthday (i.e. ignore Feb 29th & possible seasonal effects) and, given the specified distribution of birthdays, what is the probability that these 60 people had been chosen at random?

Comment: Are you sure SO is the right place for this question?

Comment: @TonyMorland what do you mean by "what is the probability that these 60 people are chosen at random" ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics, not programming.

Comment: This will seem nitpicky, but whether a particular set of people have been chosen "randomly" is unanswerable.  (If I pick 60 people according to some arbitrary formula, and someone else picks 60 people by rolling a die, how could you tell which is which?)  I think you meant "If 60 people are chosen at random from a population in which any day is equally likely to be a person's birthday, what is the probability that there are 11 days on which exactly 2 people share a birthday, one day on which exactly 3 of them share a birthday, and no days on which 4 or more people share a birthday?"

Comment: Thank you "j_random_hacker", your comment does not at all seem nitpicky, and in fact you have correctly expressed exactly what I intended with the question.  Much appreciated.

Comment: To those who choose to simply dismiss my question outright:  Perhaps you could be a little more helpful to new users who ask questions in good faith with the (perhaps mistaken) belief that SO people are likely to be the best, brightest & most able to answer questions that, despite not explicitly displaying any code, are nevertheless definitely computer-related and do fall within the scope of the available SO tags. Please, in future, could you be so kind as to suggest where questioners might find other people better qualified to answer such questions, if not yourselves?

Answer (score 0):

If my calculations are correct, then the odds that a group of 60 people has one Triple and 11 Pairs is

```
       365*1*1          364*1          363*1                354*1    1    353   352         319
60c3 * ------- * 57c2 * ----- * 55c2 * ----- * ... * 37c2 * ----- * --- * --- * --- * ... * ---
        365^3           365^2          365^2                365^2   11!   365   365         365
```

which comes out to be 0.0036%.

Note that `60c3` means "60 choose 3" which is the same as `60! / (57! * 3!)`.  Also note that the `1/11!` fudge factor is due to the fact that you have 11 pairs that can be rearranged in any order.  The code I used to compute the percentage is shown below. You should check it, and the formula above for accuracy. Use at your own risk. No warranty is expressed or implied.

```
double result, people, daysleft;

// start with the triplets: 60c3 * 365 / 365^3
result = (60.0 * 59.0 * 58.0) / (6.0 * 365.0 * 365.0);

// now consider the pairs:  Nc2 * daysleft / 365^2
people = 57.0;
daysleft = 364.0;
for ( i = 0; i < 11; i++ )
{
    result *= (people * (people - 1.0) * daysleft) / (2.0 * 365.0 * 365.0);
    people -= 2.0;
    daysleft -= 1.0;
}

// there are 11 factorial ways to rearrange the pairs
for ( i = 11; i > 0; i-- )
    result /= (double)i;

// finish up with the unique birthdays
for ( i = 0; i < 35; i++ )
{
    result *= daysleft / 365.0;
    daysleft -= 1.0;
}

printf( "%lf%%\n", result * 100.0 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply user3386109, much appreciated. The code looks consistent with the formula, and the formula looks intuitively reasonable ... i just need to convince myself of its correctness.